# Can't Replace Arabic Characters

Tags: java, arabic, replaceall

So I'm trying to replace Arabic characters with specific numbers, but the problem is that Arabic characters change depending on where they are placed in the sentence thus breaking the code.
For instance, the letter "م" is "ﻣ" when placed at the beginning of the sentence, "ﻤ" in the middle and "ﻢ" at the end.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
        File text = new File("C:/Users/LENOUVO/Desktop/AR_ar.json");
    String oldContent = "";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(text));
    
    String line = reader.readLine();
    
    while (line != null) {
        oldContent = oldContent + line + System.lineSeparator();
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    
    reader.close();
    
    String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll("ا", "{00311}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("أ", "{00312}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("ﺑ", "{00313}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("ﻟ", "{00314}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("ﺒ", "{00315}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("ﺮ", "{00316}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("ﻌ", "{00317}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("ﻴ", "{00318}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("ﺔ", "{00319}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("ر", "{00320}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("ﻠ", "{00321}");
    newContent = newContent.replaceAll("ﻐ", "{00322}");
    
    
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(text);
    writer.write(newContent);
    
    writer.close();
}
```

Inputted text:

> العربية

Outputted text:

> {00311}لع{00320}بية

Comment: The quote marks on your `String` literals in calls to `replaceAll` look wrong to me. But I’ve not had my coffee yet.

Comment: Why are you using `replaceAll` rather than `replace`? Are you aware that `replaceAll` uses a regex pattern, and that `{` and `}` have special meanings in regular expressions? I suspect that just using `replace` may well fix the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a work around to get the text as string and then convert it to list and then replace the characters you need to replace. hope it is useful.

```
  val st = "بِسْمِ اِ۬للَّهِ اِ۬لرَّحْمَٰنِ اِ۬لرَّحِيمِ ِّ"
val list = st.toMutableList()
var count = 0
for (i in list){
  if (i.equals('ن',true)){
      list[count] = 'ں'
  }
    count++

}
for (i in list){
    val file =  File("kan.txt")
    file.appendText(i.toString())


}
```